# Limit number of characters in input based on input width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to limit number of characters in input based on input width?

I have input which can have different width and I want to allow user to type characters and be sure that all typed characters will be "visible" in input so width of typed text will not be longer than input width.

I cannot use maxLength because there are different fonts and languages and letters and other characters have different width.

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question?

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(input).val.width()=$(input).width();
});
```

> i am not sure but logic could be like this.